# Create a new column from conditions in nested for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, subset, lapply

I am trying to create a new column in my dataset that tells me if a product's revenue has 0s for all 3 months, some 0s for all 3 months, or no 0s for all 3 months.

I've provided `NewColumn` as what I would like the result to look like.

```
data$ZEROES <- 0
data$ZEROES2 <- 0
for (i in unique(data$product_id)){
    for (j in unique(data$Revenue)){
        n[j] <-ifelse(all(data$Value == 0)," ALL 0", 
        ifelse(any(data$Value == 0),"Some 0", 
        ifelse(all(data$Value != 0), "None 0", "Blank")))
    data$ZEROES[j] <-n[j]
    data$ZEROES2[i] <-long$ZEROES[j]
    }
} 

product_ id Date         Revenue           Value    NewColumn
1           January       in               0           Some 0   
1           February      in               1           Some 0 
1           March         in               0           Some 0 
1           January       out              0           All 0 
1           February      out              0           All 0 
1           March         out              0           All 0 
2           January       in               1           No 0 
2           February      in               2           No 0 
2           March         in               3           No 0 
2           January       out              1           Some 0 
2           February      out              1           Some 0 
2           March         out              0           Some 0
```

Data

```
structure(list(product_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
               Date = c("January", "February", "March", "January", "February", "March", "January", "February", "March", "January", "February", "March"),
               Revenue = c("in", "in", "in", "out", "out", "out", "in", "in", "in", "out", "out", "out"),
               Value = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
               NewColumn = c("Some 0",  "Some 0", "Some 0", "All 0", "All 0", "All 0", "No 0", "No 0",  "No 0", "Some 0", "Some 0", "Some 0")),
          .Names = c("product_id",  "Date", "Revenue", "Value", "NewColumn"),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: god forbid you people add the data you used in your answers for others

Comment: good call, I normally try to include it (as a reminder to the OP) and forgot this time, I'm glad @flightless13wings was paying attention :-)

Comment: Thank @rawr for editing my initial question and adding the data.

Comment: Did one of the answers resolve your problem? If so, it's customary to accept an answer by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@thelatemail's solution is concise. Here are two alternative solutions:

1. Base R:

   ```
   do.call("rbind", by(dat, list(dat$product_id, dat$Revenue), FUN = function(df) {
     within(df, NewColumn <- ifelse(all(Value == 0), "All 0",
                                    ifelse(all(Value != 0), "No 0", "Some 0")))
   }))
   #    product_id     Date Revenue Value NewColumn
   # 1           1  January      in     0    Some 0
   # 2           1 February      in     1    Some 0
   # 3           1    March      in     0    Some 0
   # 7           2  January      in     1      No 0
   # 8           2 February      in     2      No 0
   # 9           2    March      in     3      No 0
   # 4           1  January     out     0     All 0
   # 5           1 February     out     0     All 0
   # 6           1    March     out     0     All 0
   # 10          2  January     out     1    Some 0
   # 11          2 February     out     1    Some 0
   # 12          2    March     out     0    Some 0
   ```
2. With `dplyr`

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   dat %>%
     group_by(product_id, Revenue) %>%
     mutate(
       NewColumn = ifelse(all(Value == 0), "All 0",
                          ifelse(all(Value != 0), "No 0", "Some 0"))
     )
   # Source: local data frame [12 x 5]
   # Groups: product_id, Revenue [4]
   #    product_id     Date Revenue Value NewColumn
   #         <int>    <chr>   <chr> <int>     <chr>
   # 1           1  January      in     0    Some 0
   # 2           1 February      in     1    Some 0
   # 3           1    March      in     0    Some 0
   # 4           1  January     out     0     All 0
   # 5           1 February     out     0     All 0
   # 6           1    March     out     0     All 0
   # 7           2  January      in     1      No 0
   # 8           2 February      in     2      No 0
   # 9           2    March      in     3      No 0
   # 10          2  January     out     1    Some 0
   # 11          2 February     out     1    Some 0
   # 12          2    March     out     0    Some 0
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll give it try with my real data.

Answer (score 5):

In base R you could make a custom function and then use `ave` to do the calculations within each group:

```
f <- function(x) if(all(x)) 3 else if(any(x)) 2 else 1
c("None","Some","All")[with(dat, ave(Value==0, list(product_id,Revenue), FUN=f))]
# [1] "Some" "Some" "Some" "All"  "All"  "All"  "None" "None" "None" "Some"
#[11] "Some" "Some"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, NewColumn := c("No 0", "Some 0", "All 0")[(all(!Value) + 
                        any(!Value))+1], .(product_id, Revenue)]
#    product_id     Date Revenue Value NewColumn
# 1:          1  January      in     0    Some 0
# 2:          1 February      in     1    Some 0
# 3:          1    March      in     0    Some 0
# 4:          1  January     out     0     All 0
# 5:          1 February     out     0     All 0
# 6:          1    March     out     0     All 0
# 7:          2  January      in     1      No 0
# 8:          2 February      in     2      No 0
# 9:          2    March      in     3      No 0
#10:          2  January     out     1    Some 0
#11:          2 February     out     1    Some 0
#12:          2    March     out     0    Some 0
```